# value of type results has no member realm swift2

Tags: uitableview, swift2, realm

I have data saved in a Realm that I am trying to display in a custom tableview cell. Here is the code.

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> JobTableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JobCell") as! JobTableViewCell

```
    //var jobs: Results<Job>?

    let jobs = realm.objects(Job) as String

        cell.nameLabel?.text = jobs.name
        cell.addressLabel?.text = jobs.address
        cell.phoneLabel?.text = jobs.phone
        cell.emailLabel?.text = jobs.email
    return cell
}
```

I am getting the error "Value of type'Results<(Job)> (aka 'Results) has no member 'name'. This error repeats on all four label lines.

I have tried to cast the type to String which eliminates the errors on the label lines, but creates a new error "Cannot convert value of type '(Job)' ... to expected argument type 'T.Type'

I am new to this so please excuse me if my post is not done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

`realm.objects(Job) as String`

The you're trying to convert `Results<Job>` to a string, which is not a compatible type.

You probably want to apply the values of the item in some Realm `Results` at the index of `indexPath.row` to your cell's UI components like this:

```
let job = realm.objects(Job)[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel?.text = job.name
cell.addressLabel?.text = job.address
cell.phoneLabel?.text = job.phone
cell.emailLabel?.text = job.email
```

Comment: It worked!  Maybe one day I'll get the hangs of this.